# Looking for KornShell (ksh93) User Defined Type (typeset -T) documentation/examples

Tags: ksh

A couple of months ago I came across [Musings of an OS plumber](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/). The one posting that really caught my attention was [Using Types To Create Object Orientated Korn Shell 93 Scripts](https://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/05/ksh93-using-types-to-create-object-orientated-scripts.html).

Ever since then I have been searching the Web looking for more information/examples of them. In all that time I've come to the conclusion that they are very rare because I have only found 3 examples and 3 documents (one of which is 'Type Variables' in the ksh93 man page).

If anybody here knows where I can find more on this feature then please can you pass it on to me. My plan is to write an article on this and post it here. I know of at least one person that would find it helpful.

Comment: I found the same blog. I wrote a couple of example programs, found at https://github.com/glennj/exercism.io/tree/main/ksh

Comment: Look on ebay for the book about `dtksh`. I'd bet the author (David Korn's son) will have used those features. Good luck

Comment: make that https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7495/6jgc7ae04/index.html

Comment: @glennjackman; Thanks for the link. The example ksh scripts contained some info that I was not aware of.

Comment: @shellter; Thanks for the suggestion but was unable to find anything relevent. From what I have seen it looks as if typeset -T first appeared in ksh93t and dtksh doesn't use it (unless you, or somebody else knows differently).

Comment: oh wow, `93t`? I didn't realize that `-T` was such a "late" feature. I recall David K commenting in a at&t tech ksh thread that it was too much trouble to get a stds committee to accept a new "name" to reflect improvements. (`93t` should have probably  been `2005` or even later). Good luck with your project!

Comment: I don't recall seeing anything about the -T functionality in any books but I have not studied the dtksh book, either.  The group I work for uses ksh with -T types extensively, partly because we are (distantly) descended from David Korn's group.  It's out there and works and even works in the boogered up ksh 2020 I have on Ubuntu (installed with `sudo apt-get install ksh`).  Let me see if I can come up with a generic, if not overly useful example.

Comment: @user1683793; Anything you are willing to share will be received with thanks. I am running ksh93u+m/1.0.7 from the ksh93/ksh GitHub repository which has code back-ported from 93v and 2020 installed.

Answer (score 0):

The `ksh` language is pretty neat and I'm glad somebody is taking an interest in the underused features.  (Language?! Quite so, it is a fully functional and fairly powerful language that runs slow as... but that's another story.)

I'll give you this example and I'll fill in an explanation about what I am doing after.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ksh
# This will do a show and tell using the typeset -T feature
# of ksh
# Sat Mar 30 01:01:35 AM EDT 2024
#
typeset -T TheTime_T=(
    typeset -S skew=0
    function get {
        now=$( date +%s )
        (( .sh.value=now+skew ))
        (( skew+=1 ))
    }
)
typeset -T Upper_T=(
    TheTime_T now
    typeset one=11
    typeset two=2U
    typeset countU=0
    typeset start="Upper"
    function initialize {
        typeset -S countS=0  # static
        typeset    countI=0  # instance
        (( _.countU+=1 ))
        (( countS+=1 ))
        countI=$(( countI+1 ))
        echo "init of Upper: ${!_}  S=${countS} I=${countI} U=${_.countU}"
    }
    function setStart {
        echo "Upper:setStart ${_.now} $@"
    }
    function endStart {
        echo "Upper:endStart ${_.now} $@"
    }
)
typeset -T Middle_T=(
    Upper_T _
    typeset middleVal="middle value"
    typeset start=middle
    typeset two="middle"
    function initialize {
        echo "init of Middle: ${!_}"
        .sh.type.Upper_T.initialize ${!_}
    }
    function endStart {
        echo "Middle:endStart $@"
        _.two="midEnd"
    }
)
typeset -T Lower_T=(
    Middle_T _
    typeset one=1L
    typeset start="lower"
    function initialize {
        echo "init of Lower: ${!_}"
        .sh.type.Upper_T.initialize ${!_}
    }
    function endStart {
        echo "Lower:endStart $@"
        echo "Ending the start process in mv=${_.middleVal} t=${_.two} ${_.one}"
    }
)

Upper_T uu
uu.initialize toStart
uu.setStart hownow
uu.endStart then

Middle_T mm
mm.initialize inMiddle
mm.setStart middleStart
mm.endStart middleStartThen

Lower_T ll=(
    middleVal="lower val"
)

ll.initialize TowardsEnd
ll.setStart startingLower
ll.endStart endingLower
```

When run with ksh2020 (which is better than I remembered) this resulted in:

```
$ ./tryT.sh
init of Upper: uu  S=1 I=1 U=1
Upper:setStart 1711826692 hownow
Upper:endStart 1711826693 then
init of Middle: mm
init of Upper: Upper_T  S=2 I=1 U=1
Upper:setStart 1711826694 middleStart
Middle:endStart middleStartThen
init of Lower: ll
init of Upper: Upper_T  S=3 I=1 U=2
Upper:setStart 1711826695 startingLower
Lower:endStart endingLower
Ending the start process in mv=lower val t=midEnd lower
```

I think it is explained in the man page that `Name_T _`  means inheritance.  Class names start with caps and end with `_T`.  You don't have to but it's a good convention.  Variables that are prefixed by `_.` are class variables.

By way of explanation,
I created the `TheTime_T` class to give the idea of a get function.  "At the office," we have a `now` built-in that gives Unix seconds since 1970 but for show and tell, I created this function that counts up each time it is called so we give the idea that time is progressing.

You can see the three classes `Upper_T`, `Middle_T` and `Lower_T`, each is based upon the one above, inheriting functions (aka, methods) and variables (properties).  I'm not sure if it is in the man pages but `_` is the current object so declaring `_` to be of type `Upper_T` says that `Middle_T` is derived from `Upper_T`.

The `Upper_T.initialize` function has two count variables, one is declared with the `-S`, static. As always, static means shared between instances so the `countS` gets incremented for all instances `countI` only gets incremented for each instance. Why is `countI` incremented differently? I'll leave that as an exercise for the student (I don't know, that's what works).

A bit more about the syntax,

- You can see `_.two="midEnd"`.  (I did not need the quotes but they don't hurt.)  That sets the two variable in that `Middle_T` instance.
- Observe the `.sh.type.Upper_T.initialize ${!_}` This is calling the initialize function in that class. There's should be a way to do it with something like `_._.initialize` but it does not work.
- We see the echo of `init of Upper: ${!_}`.  When this was run as a part of a variable of type `Upper_T`, this printed the variable name.  When run when called directly from a lower class, it displayed the class name.

I put in a bunch of goofy variable manipulations that don't serve any purpose and are not particularly illustrative but maybe they will help getting the idea.

My colleague *loved* ksh to distraction and wrote massive programs with great complicated classes.  I wish he had loved Python that much so the code would be written in a language that is actually controlled and generally agreed upon rather than just what happens to work.

Questions?

Comment: @AtishtumRah You'll have to tell us if you produce an interesting article and where we can find it.  The `ksh` has a lot of advantages over `bash` but it has so many problems and so little momentum, I expect it will be forgotten by all but a few die-hards (like me).

Comment: Stack Overflow & the ksh93/ksh GitHub repository are 2 places the article will definitely be posted. It will also be posted wherever else I can manage to place it.